# Как получить список текущих уведомлений в статус баре на 17 API?

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, adb

Задача состоит в извлечении текста из уведомлений в статус баре через `adb`. На данный момент написал `Service`, который следит за уведомлениями, наследующийся от `NotificationListenerService` и `Broadcast`, который по запросу с `adb` отдает данные уведомления от определенного пакета. Но сам `NotificationListenerService` доступен только с 18 API, а поле `extras` класса `Notification` (я с него беру текст и заголовок) - с 19го.

Может есть какая-то возможность получить те же данные, но на 17ом API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К счастью, ответ найден!

Решение довольно банально - данные обо всех уведомлениях можно получить через команду `shell dumpsys notification`. Но `extras` получить пока не удалось. Правда у меня все устройства рутованные, отпишите, пожалуйста, в комментариях, работает ли без рута.